# R: Quantmod - getsymbols.csv file format?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm struggeling to read a local CSV file with quantmod's `getSymbols`. The format of the file (wkn_541779.csv) I'm trying to read is like this:

```
Date;Open;High;Low;Close;Volume;Ajdusted
2012-09-06;104,62;105,95;104,62;105,95;1248065,00;105,95
2012-09-05;104,78;104,78;104,45;104,48;1176371,00;104,48
2012-09-04;104,73;104,73;104,26;104,26;13090,00;104,26

> getSymbols("wkn_541779", src="csv", header = TRUE, sep=";", dec=",")
```

Gives me an error message: "more columns than column names" though.

```
> count.fields("wkn_541779.csv", sep = ";", skip = 0, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

Results in "7" for each line (including the header!), which is exactly the number of columns in the header.

Can anybody please help me tracking down the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSymbols.csv` calls `read.csv` with its defaults. i.e. `sep=","`

Comment: is there a way you can pass sep=";" into the getSymbols or setSymbols function?